# Is the group generated by a finite group and a compact Lie group still a compact Lie group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, compactness

Suppose we are given two matrix groups comprised of unitary matrices: a finite group $G_1$ and a compact group $G_2$. Let $G$ be the group generated by $G_1$ and $G_2$, that is, every element of $G$ is the matrix product of elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$, i.e., $U_1U_2U_3\cdots$,  where $U_i$ is either an element of $G_1$ or that of $G_2$. My question is:
Is $G$ still a compact Lie group?

If not, what kind of group could $G$ be?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The group generated by $G_1$ and $G_2$" is quite ambiguous; if you have in mind an embedding of $G_1$ and $G_2$ as subgroups in some larger group, the generated group will generally depend a lot on the embedding.

The most general possibility is the [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product), which will almost never be a compact Lie group. Already $G_2$ could be another finite group and the free product $G_1 \ast G_2$ is countable (with the discrete topology, hence noncompact) unless either $G_1$ or $G_2$ is trivial. For example, the free product $C_2 \ast C_2$ is the [infinite dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group), and the free product $C_2 \ast C_3$ is the [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

**Edit:** The answer to the revised question is still no although this is less obvious and I'm not sure how to give a complete proof off the top of my head; free products as above can embed into unitary groups (although the subspace topology will no longer be discrete, it is still noncompact). This is related to the embeddings of free groups used to prove the [Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox). For example, if we pick two elements of order $2$ in $U(2)$ uniformly at random then they generate the infinite dihedral group $C_2 \ast C_2$ with probability $1$.

However, these subgroups won't generally be *closed*, and for physical applications you may find it more natural to take the closure. The closure of any subgroup of a compact Lie group is again a compact Lie group, by the [closed subgroup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem).

Comment: Thanks. I am considering physical problems involving symmetries. In quantum physics, the group elements considered can be thought of as matrices. I have specified the question.

Comment: Thanks. This example helps a lot. Yes, in physics, it is natural to take closure and we always assume so. Do you mean it is still possible for $G$ to be not compact after taking closure (although this is not the case for the example)?

Comment: No, the closure is always compact; this is a general feature of compact topological spaces. The nontrivial statement requiring proof is that the closure is a Lie group.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the problem. Yes, $G$ is compact, as every bounded and closed set in finite-dimensional topological vector space is compact. The difficulty is to show $G$ is a Lie group. I am asking whether $G$ is still a compact Lie group (I missed the words "Lie group" in the above comment). I tend to believe that $G$ is still a compact Lie group, although I do not know how to prove this statement.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just said in my edit, and then I said it again in my comment. $G$ is still a compact Lie group, and this follows from the closed subgroup theorem.